# Drush 9 can't find installed module, yields CommandNotFoundException

Tags: 8, drush

On my newly installed Drupal 8.4.4 sandbox installation, I've installed Drush 9 and the Devel module:

```
composer require drush/drush:^9
composer require drupal/devel
```

After running these commands, I installed the Devel module using the Extend tab in Drupal.

Drush seems be be installed correctly:

```
www-data@39e134dc7690:~/html$ /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush version
Drush version : 9.1.0
```

The Devel modules seems to be installed correctly:

```
www-data@39e134dc7690:~/html$ grep -r devel-container-service /var/www/html/modules/contrib/devel/
/var/www/html/modules/contrib/devel/src/Commands/DevelCommands.php:   * @aliases devel-container-services,dcs,devel-services
/var/www/html/modules/contrib/devel/drush/devel.drush8.inc:  $items['devel-container-services'] = array(
```

But Drush doesn't seem to find the devel module:

```
www-data@39e134dc7690:~/html$ /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush devel-container-services
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
Command "devel-container-services" is not defined.
```

Are there any path settings I need to tweak to get Drush to find the Devel module?

Comment: `drush cc drush; composer dump-autoload; drush cr`. Any better after running that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ran the commands you suggested, but unfortunately thing still fail:

    www-data@39e134dc7690:~/html$ export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/html/vendor/bin drush cc drush; composer dump-autoload; drush cr; drush devel-container-services
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess
 [success] Cache rebuild complete.
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "devel-container-services" is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like I simply had forgotten to enable (i.e install) the module in /admin/modules. I had just ran "composer require", but not actually enabled it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when attempting to port an older global Drush command. While following the [porting instructions](https://weitzman.github.io/blog/port-to-drush9) generated the necessary Drush code, the command was not discovered by drush because it wasn't part of an enabled module.

If this is your issue, either create a module_name.info.yml file manually, or run `drush generate module`, then enable the module in question. The drush command no longer threw a `CommandNotFoundException`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll test this when I get the chance. But before that I need to verify that I actually enabled (i.e. click "install" in the Drupal GUI) the Devel module in Drupal after installing it - it's possible I forgot to enable it.